# Porqué en Java Netbeans me lanza una excepcion NullPointerException si estoy inicializando todos los objetos?

Tags: java, netbeans, nullpointerexception

tengo una duda, soy nuevo en Java, y estoy escribiendo un programa, al momento de intentar acceder a los métodos de un objeto al que ya le asigné una referencia.

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;
import java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException;

class MueblePiezas implements Serializable{
    private Mueble mueble;
    private String tipoDeMueble;
    private Pieza pieza;
    private int cantidadDePiezas;
    private String path;
    private String tipoDePieza;

    FileController comunicador = new FileController();
    VentanaIngresoMedianteArchivo escritor = new VentanaIngresoMedianteArchivo();

    public MueblePiezas(String mueble, String pieza, int cantidadDePiezas){
        this.tipoDeMueble=mueble;
        this.tipoDePieza=pieza;
        this.cantidadDePiezas=cantidadDePiezas;
    }
    public MueblePiezas(){}

    Mueble getMueble(){
        return this.mueble;
    }
    Pieza getPieza(){
        return this.pieza;
    }
    Integer getCantidadDePiezas(){
        return this.cantidadDePiezas;
    }

    void evaluarLinea(String line) {
        try{
        StringTokenizer token = new StringTokenizer(line, ",");
        tipoDeMueble=token.nextToken()
                .replaceAll("MUEBLE_PIEZAS", "")
                .replace("(", "")
                .replace("\"", "");
        tipoDePieza=token.nextToken()
                .replace("\"", "");      
        cantidadDePiezas=Integer.valueOf(
                token.nextToken()
                .replace(")",""));
        path="Mueble"+tipoDeMueble+".mueble";
        mueble=comunicador.leerMueble(path);
        path="Pieza"+tipoDePieza+".pieza";
        pieza=comunicador.leerPieza(path);
        String tipoDeMueble= mueble.getNombreMueble();                                                       
        String tipoDePieza= pieza.getTipo();                                      // <== Error 
        MueblePiezas mueblePieza = new MueblePiezas(tipoDeMueble,tipoDePieza,cantidadDePiezas);
        String nombreMueblePieza="MueblePieza"+tipoDeMueble+tipoDePieza+".mpza";
        FileController.escribirObjeto(nombreMueblePieza, mueblePieza);
        }

    catch(NoSuchElementException e ){
        escritor.modificarTexto("Instruccion incompleta, por lo tanto, no se ha ingresado al sistema");
    }
    catch(PatternSyntaxException e){
        escritor.modificarTexto("Error en la sintaxis de la instruccion, por lo tanto, no se ha ingresado");
    }    
    catch(NumberFormatException e){
        escritor.modificarTexto("Error al leer los datos de la cantidad de piezas, no se ingreso la instruccion");
    }  
    }

}
```

La clase que lee los objeto desde los archivos es el siguiente

```
public class FileController implements Serializable {
    private static ObjectInputStream fileIn = null;
    private static VentanaIngresoMedianteArchivo escritor = new VentanaIngresoMedianteArchivo();

    public static void escribirObjeto(String nombre, Object objeto){
    try{
        ObjectOutputStream fileOut = new ObjectOutputStream(
        new FileOutputStream(nombre));
        fileOut.writeObject(objeto);
        fileOut.close();
        }
        catch (IOException e){
        System.out.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public static Usuario leerUsuario(String path){
        Usuario usuario = null;
        try{
            fileIn = new ObjectInputStream(
            new FileInputStream(path));
            usuario = (Usuario) fileIn.readObject();
            fileIn.close();
        }
        catch (IOException e){
            escritor.modificarTexto("IO Error: " + e.getMessage());
        }
        catch (ClassNotFoundException e){
            escritor.modificarTexto("ClassNotFound " + e.getMessage());
        }
        return usuario;
    }

    Mueble leerMueble(String path){
        Mueble mueble = null;
        try{
            fileIn = new ObjectInputStream(
            new FileInputStream(path));
            mueble = (Mueble) fileIn.readObject();
            fileIn.close();
        }
        catch (IOException e){
            escritor.modificarTexto("IO Error: " + e.getMessage());
        }
        catch (ClassNotFoundException e){
            escritor.modificarTexto("ClassNotFound " + e.getMessage());
        }
        return mueble;
    }


    Pieza leerPieza(String path){
        Pieza pieza = null;
        try{
            fileIn = new ObjectInputStream(
            new FileInputStream(path));
            pieza = (Pieza) fileIn.readObject();
            fileIn.close();
        }
        catch (IOException e){
            escritor.modificarTexto("IO Error: " + e.getMessage());
        }
        catch (ClassNotFoundException e){
            escritor.modificarTexto("ClassNotFound " + e.getMessage());
        }
        return pieza;
    }   
}
```

No se porque me lanza este error, ya intente de todo. Gracias amigos.

Comment: puedes confirmar que pieza=comunicador.leerPieza(path); no devuelve null?. Como está escrita la función leerPieza ésta puede devolver null si falla la lectura del archivo.

Comment: Generalmente las NullPointerException pueden ser por variables que devuelven Null, si estás haciendo referencia a una ruta que no existe, te va a dar NullPointerException, por ejemplo.